# Extracting pixels with value in one raster but NoData in other raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have two raster A and B, and they are representing the info for Florida. Ideally A and B should have same coverage. However, due to some data processing issue, B's boundary is a bit smaller than A's. This means there are pixels with value in A, but NoData in B. Not just along the boundary, within B's coverage, there are a few holes, meaning pixel value is NoData. My question is how I should extract these pixels to form a new raster, as well as making their pixel value same as A's.

Comment: Raster calculator Con(IsNull("B"),"A","B") or simply mosaic to new raster